# PromQL Query Help (Prometheus inside Grafana)

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I have an issue I am hoping to receive some assistance on. I have SQL experience but little to no PromQL experience.
I have been tasked with constructing a view within Grafana to show average usages for a specific time frame (as an example: Two Mondays ago from 8PM to 2AM).

avg(((1 - (
_Memory_AvailableMBytes{customer_name=~"[[Customer]]",business_service=~"[[BusinessService]]",product_code=~"[[Product]]", environment_type=~"[[Environment]]",function_code!~".*Database.*",type!="server.dbnode"} / 1000) /
Ram{customer_name=~"[[Customer]]",business_service=~"[[BusinessService]]", product_code=~"[[Product]]",environment_type=~"$Environment",function_code!~".*Database.*",type!="server.dbnode"}) * 100) )

This is where I am starting. How can I add specific servers and specific timeframes to this query? I am working to learn all the various syntaxes but I am unfortunately under the gun.

Any assistance would be amazing!